# How to format a column as 'currency' and delete the currency present currency string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, currency-format

My excel file contains a column with numbers and text like this

```
2,34 EUR
64,34 EUR
9,98 EUR
```

I want to format the column as a currency.
Currently I delete the 'EUR' text (e.g. manually or with search and replace, some people even use VBA) and then set the column number type as a currency.

To me this seems to be quite complicated for something that seems so simple like formatting a cell that contains a number and a currency symbol. Is there a way to do this with one or two clicks?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built in way, but if you write a macro, you should be able to run it with one or two clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**Data > Text to Columns**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7):

1. Select the currency column
2. Choose **Data > Text to Columns**.
3. Select **Delimited**, then click **Next**
4. Specify that you need a **Space** as the Delimiter and click
   **Next**
5. Leave the type of the first column (with numbers) - **Standard**
6. Select the second column and set **Do not import column (skip)**
7. Click **Finish** and get the result

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was looking for.